# Android java - Trying to show snackbar in new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-snackbar

Ive been trying to make my bluetooth connection thread be able to send messages to the user through snackbars, but they never appear on the screen.

In main method:

```
//listener for connect button
    try {
        Button btn_connect = findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if(bluetoothService.isStarted()){
                snackbarMsg(findViewById(R.id.btn_connect), "Bluetooth connection already established");
            } else{
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "New thread started");
                        bluetoothService.run(MainActivity.this);
                        Log.i(TAG,"Bluetooth service started");
                        snackbarMsg(findViewById(R.id.btn_connect), "Bluetooth service started");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth service failed", e);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth service failed");
    }
```

in BluetoothService class:

```
public void snackbarMsg (View view, String msg){
    try {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT);

        snackbar.show();
    } catch (Exception exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not show snackbar", exception);
    }
}
```

The view i send with the method is always of something on the main screen, so for example using "snackbarMsg(findViewById(R.id.button_send),"Failed to find bluetooth server");"
where button_send is on the screen i want to show the snackbar.

ive tried using runnables and extends thread and whatnot. But since i already have extensions on bluetoothservice class that didnt work, and runnable proved troublesome because i need to send context when starting the run method, and that context seemingly cant be sent at an earlier state, meaning i cant send that info when i create and object fom bluetoothservice at the beginning of the program.

Secondly: im not sure i even need a second thread, since my bluetooth connection is only sending data, not receiving, am i just doing useless work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it on the UI/Main thread.

Use [runOnUiThread(action: Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```
runOnUiThread(() -> snackbarMsg(view, "insert message"));
```

Comment: hmm, okay. I tried using this but could not understand how i would make snackbarMsg into a "runnable". I implemented it now, but still it did not show any snackbar. I tried simply not using another thread, but it still didnt work so i think i may have a different problem entirely.

Comment: The method accepts a Runnable and that is where you run your Snackbar method. You cannot modify the view by not using the UI/Main thread, this is the problem.